# ASP.NET Core 7 when receiving an object data from Http POST binding invalid properties

Tags: asp.net-core, http, modelbinders

When receiving an object from a client on a Http API endpoint - and that object comes in as a C# object (`FromBody`) - is there any way to detect if the client has added a property that is not part of the expected object?

Say for instance we were to receive an object of a class that was defined as:

```
public class SomeData 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and the data that was sent from a client is

```
{
    "id": 56,
    "name": "JimBob",
    "Something": "Some other piece of data not expected"
}
```

Is there any way to get told by the .NET data binders that we received an invalid property?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of "being notified" of unexpected properties, there is no built-in way. Also, you can't simply tell model binder to "add any extra properties to a model". However, you can implement a middleware to intercept the received body data and alter it however you want. With such middleware, you can theoretically achieve what you want.

Here is what I did in a project. It involved taking data from body and parsing it into a meaningful model.

```
public class RequestBodyParser
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestBodyParser(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith("GetPaged")) // which exact requests do you want to process? you probably don't want to process every request, so specify a path here.
        {
            try
            {
                // Read the request body
                var reqBody = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                if (reqBody == null || !reqBody.StartsWith("draw")) await _next(context); // just an extra check

                // URL decode the request body
                var decodedBody = Uri.UnescapeDataString(reqBody);
                if (decodedBody == null) await _next(context);

                // Split the decoded body into key-value pairs
                var keyValuePairs = decodedBody.Split('&')
                    .Select(part => part.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split.Length > 1 ? split[1] : "");

                DataTablesRequestModel dataTableReqModel = new DataTablesRequestModel(); // in my case, I have a certain model and I instantiate an object in its type to inject it into HttpRequest

                // for example, here I extract a certain key's value and use it
                keyValuePairs.TryGetValue("draw", out string draw);
                dataTableReqModel.Draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw);

                // do whatever else you need to do..

                context.Items["ReqBody"] = dataTableReqModel;// Store the parsed data in HttpContext.Items
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log
                await _next(context);
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And register the middleware like this. You can put it just before routing middleware:

```
app.UseMiddleware<RequestBodyParser>(); // our custom middleware    
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

And here is how you would use the custom request data in your controller actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPaged()
{
    try
    {
        var reqBody = (DataTablesRequestModel?)HttpContext.Items["ReqBody"];
        // do stuff...
```

In theory, you can parse body into your expected model (which contain all expected properties), and add a `Dictionary<string, string>` property and add any extra/unexpected properties into it as a key-value pair. The `keyValuePairs` variable in middleware will contain everything in the request body. What the middleware does is inject an object into `HttpContext.Items`, which you can access within the same request scope in preceding handlers, similar to passing a `ViewData` or `TempData` to views.

All that being said, you should keep security in mind. Accepting any extra properties seems like a risky approach. Having a predefined list of all expected properties would be an infinitely healthier approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned you are working with .NET 7,it would deserialize the jsonstring in request body  to target object with `System.Text.Json`

The most simple solution  I know:

create a DTO:

```
public class SomeDataDTO:SomeData 
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement>? ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

check if ExtensionData  is null in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]SomeDataDTO someData)
{
    if (someData.ExtensionData != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "JsonOverFlow");
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-8-0) related